# SSIS Package not running failing on CMD

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

Good Day,

I am trying to run a package, but no matter what I try, it is not working.  It fails with the following message

> Executed as user: NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE. Microsoft (R) SQL Server
>   Execute Package Utility  Version 10.50.1600.1 for 32-bit  Copyright
>   (C) Microsoft Corporation 2010. All rights reserved.    Started: 
>   12:59:18 PM  DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_SUCCESS (0)
>   but had warnings, with warnings being treated as errors.  Started: 
>   12:59:18 PM  Finished: 12:59:55 PM  Elapsed:  37.315 seconds.  The
>   command line parameters are invalid.  The step failed.

I did check my cmd line that is executed when I try to parse it to test if it is correct.  I get another error message:

> /DTS "\File System\FileToSQL" /SERVER PULSITSRVAPP /WARNASERROR /X86  /CHECKPOINTING OFF /REPORTING E

If I parse it I get:

> Incorrect syntax near '/'. (Microsoft SQL Server Error:102)

I am not getting anywhere with my problem.  Can someone please provide some clue to test and see if I can resolve this problem.

Thank You

Comment: Have you used the [Execute Package Utility](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140258(v=sql.105).aspx) to build your command line?

Comment: No not yet first time i am doing this so i am very new to this, let me see how it works an try it quikly

Comment: If i Execute it from there is is working fine and no errors

Comment: I spoke to quick it did give errors now was working perfect the last time i executed it from the SSIS instance

Comment: The Problem with the errors when running the execute package utility is solved i had a duplicate file in the mix, i deleted the file executed it again and it worked 100% no errors but when i execyte the job is still gives me the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved as per Andrews comment i copied the value from the command line entry in the Execute Package Utility and replaced it with the line in my step in JobShedule this solved the problem and the package executed successfully thank you Andrew.

Old Line: 
/DTS "\File System\FileToSQL" /SERVER PULSITSRVAPP /WARNASERROR /X86 /CHECKPOINTING OFF /REPORTING E

Replaced Value: 
/DTS "\File System\FileToSQL" /SERVER PULSITSRVAPP /CHECKPOINTING OFF  /REPORTING V

This Solved my problem.